# Creating black/white squares using matlab

Tags: matlab, shapes

I'have to create these three simple squares in Matlab:

[image]

Can anyone give me a hand? I know how to use images by openning them (imread) but I dont know how to create them on matlab from 0.

Comment: possibly related: [Creating a bi-color image in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665929/creating-a-bi-color-image-in-matlab)

Comment: I already read that one. But it seems a different thing, as the 3rth image is imposible to do on that way.

Comment: Have you tried reading the online help? Searching on google? Tell us :-)

Comment: Sure I did. That's why I'm asking. This website is always my last resort. And I'm not a 20 year old guy, so show due respect, I'm a programmer but I'm just new with this (matlab)

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't mean to offend you. Once you know that for MATLAB an image is just a matrix, [this](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/math/f1-84864.html) is a good starting point to read.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help. Will give a look to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create image number 3, you have to remember that an image is just a matrix, and that black and white can be represented by 0 and 1, respectively. So the question becomes: How can you create a 2D array in Matlab that is all zeros except for some specific region?

```
%# create an empty image (all zeros)
%# use a logical image, since all we want to show 
%# are black and white

img = false(256,256);

%# to add the square, make the top left quarter white
%# by setting the pixel values to true (i.e. 1)

img(1:128,1:128) = true;

%# show the image
figure,imshow(img)
```

[image]

Comment: May I suggest that image #3 can also be constructed by combining both images #1 and #2 and then inverting the values.

Answer (score 0):

[pcolor](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/pcolor.html) might be an option

```
pcolor(hadamard(20))
colormap(gray(2))
axis ij
axis square
```

Comment: Hello zellus. Thanks for the reply. The problem is that "pcolor" creates me little squares and I want a 2 color cube. No more squares than the cube itself. Thanks